# Nexus 7 2013 wi-fi stuck at google logo after rooting

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, bootloader

I downloaded AOSP (5.1.1, API level 22), made changes in the `init.rc`, and added the `su` binary / SuperUser packages to the build. I also added proprietary binaries relevant to nexus-7 flo (for Android 5.1.1 (LMY47V)). I then built the entire source tree to get a package (.zip) containing the required .img files and Android-info.txt. I then do a fastboot -w "zip file name with all imgs".

This runs and the device gets stuck in the "Google" screen with a lock icon. It does not go beyond that even after hours. However, I can access the tablet via ADB and I also get root shell. What am I missing here ? Is there a version mismatch somewhere ? How do I check if that is the case.

Additional details :
Device is "flo". At the launch menu I selected "flo-userdebug". 
Repository sync is to the latest android version I think. I checked the version in `build/core/version_defaults.mk`.

What could be the issue?

Comment: That is not the general way to root a Nexus device. Also, your question seems remarkably similar to this one: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129817/nexus-7-stuck-on-googles-logo-after-flashed-the-building-of-aosp , are you the same user who posted that question?

Comment: No i found my answer. There was a mismatch between the different versions  I was using for proprietary binaries... Its way too late to go on without an answer...

Comment: You could answer your own question, but development, including ROM development, is off-topic here