# Nexus 7 stuck on google's logo after flashed the building of AOSP

Tags: rom-flashing, nexus-7, 5.1-lollipop

This is my first time to flash the AOSP build on the device. I just followed Google's instructions to download and build the Android source code. Since I have a Nexus 7 (2013), so I chose the target to "aosp_flo-userdebug" before starting to build. Then I ran "make" to build, and the building was successful.

After that I rebooted the device and went into the bootloader, flashed the device by the command:

`$ fastboot -w flashall`

The flash succeeded. Then after the device rebooted, it just got stuck on the Google's logo screen and never continued. If I flash it back to the factory image, it can continue booting. So I think maybe there are some mistakes I made during the building or flashing that causes the problem. But I don't know how to find the problem.

I also tried to flash only system.img by:

`$ fastboot flash system system.img`

But it's still the same result. Hope someone can give me some suggestions. Thanks.

PS: the build version is 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Tamoghna Chowdhury for linking this to a similar question i had posted. I had similar issues and struggled with it for a while. You need to check some things. Did you flash the device specific binaries ?

In my case there was a version mismatch with the device specific binary  and the device. FLO should always have FLO binaries. Otherwise it wont start. Check this post

https://code.google.com/p/aosp4nexus5/wiki/AOSPforNexus5#Automatic_Installatin_of_GApps

I did this long ago, so I don't remember exact step i had take, If you post details of what you have done, maybe i'll remember something.

EDIT :Updating answer based on below comment from OP

Use the second link you mentioned https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#flolrx22g

Your device is flo. That is the first step. Now, your AOSP build should match with the binaries version. So you cant use 5.1.51 along with binaries of version LMY48G since that is for 5.1.1 . SO checkout AOSP with the same version, i.e 5.1.1 in your case and build again with the LMY48G binaries. I remember i had the same issue but with version 5.0.1 i.e LRX22G. It worked when i checkedout an older source code.

I dont know why this happens, ideally any new version should work. Perhaps another quirks of android.  I did not update android later on when the tablet booted correctly. Too big a risk to take :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think I missed the device specific binaries on previous building. So I downloaded the binaries for flo (LMY48G), and ran a building again. But still doesn't work. I noticed there are a bunch of binaries on Google. https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/blobs-preview and https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#flo, I think maybe I used the wrong version of binaries. But how to know which version should I use? The source I'm using is 5.1.51

Comment: I solved my problem by getting the binaries from  https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/blobs-preview eventually. Thanks again.

Comment: I think this is now documented in the official site: "AOSP cannot be used from pure source code only and requires additional hardware-related proprietary libraries to run, specifically for hardware graphics acceleration."https://source.android.com/source/running.html#obtaining-proprietary-binaries

Comment: This also explains why the preview binaries are needed: "To instead build the AOSP master branch, use the Binaries Preview for Nexus Devices." Anyway, thanks for the sharing : D

Answer (score 0):

Download binary can solve this issue
for example
https://developers.google.com/android/drivers#tilapialmy47d

download all the link, untar *.tgz, and execute all shell script.
Then rebuild code.